# Is first Ubuntu user root?

Tags: sudo, root, users

When I set up Ubuntu system for the first time, and create first user, will that user be `root`? I would like to use `sudo` user, so how to add it if first user is `root`? Also is it possible to create `sudo` user withoute `root` user?

Comment: The first user won't be root. So there is no problem.

Comment: root will be user id 0.  daemon 1, bin 2 .... 
The first "real" user set up will be id 1000.

Comment: with the first user ... ```sudo su -``` ....

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The first user won't be root. The first user will have sudo permissions.
So just install Ubuntu and you'll have exactly what you wanted.

The root user will be created behind the scene, but root login will be disabled.

Comment: The user will be added to the *sudo*-group, which would let the user use `sudo` to become **root** (after entering his password).  (A less flexible way, would've been to make an entry for the user in */etc/sudoers*.)

Comment: @BaardKopperud Does Ubuntu use the wheel group as well?

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez No, I believe Ubuntu out of the box has no `wheel` group.

Comment: `wheel` group is not implemented in Debian by default, and Ubuntu is based on that, hence why there's no `wheel` group in Ubuntu. See [Why is Debian not creating the wheel group by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4460/85039)

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez   **wheel** is the GID=0 group on BSD-systems, whereas Linux uses **root**.  On BSD-systems **wheel** (GID=0) is used to list all users allowed to become *root* - in fact, only member of **wheel** are allowed to execute `su` at all.  On Linux, the **root** (GID=0) groups is used very differently - few if any users are added, and usually only system-users (no real human users)... one example was the **operator** user, which used to run back-ups on Linux-systems (it needed root-group for access to files).  TBC

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez On most (all?) current Linux-systems, the **wheel** group is not included.  I do however remember it on early version of Slackware among others.  In any way, there are plenty of room to add it to the lower GIDs in the /etc/group-file (below 20 or 50) - and there are plenty of room to add it later (eg. between 100 or 200, and 500).  Further more, the **wheel**-group was mentioned in the *sudoers*-example file, as a good way to list users allowed to become *root* (while the **sudo**-group was mentioned for users allowed to become root without their password).